# Applescript property setter not working correctly -- howto?

Tags: cocoa, applescript

I have a `<property>` in my Cocoa project's sdef file, and I can get my Applescripts to read the property correctly, but I can't get them to set it (I get an error in the Applescript Editor).

My sdef is pasted below. Is there a special convention for the property? I would have thought it'd just be `- (void) setLength:(NSNumber *)len;`. Is it not?

`

```
<xi:include href="file:///System/Library/ScriptingDefinitions/CocoaStandard.sdef"
            xpointer="xpointer(/dictionary/suite)"/>


<suite name="Timer Scripting" code="StTs"
       description="Commands and classes for Timer">

    <command name="createtimer" code="sttscret" description="Create a new timer">
    </command>

    <class name="application" code="smgT"
           description="Timer application">

        <cocoa class="NSApplication"/>

        <property name="length"
                  code="tlen"
                  type="integer"
                  access="rw"
                  description="length of timer in seconds"/>

        <responds-to name="createtimer">
            <cocoa method="createTimer:"/>
        </responds-to>
    </class>
</suite>
```

`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a problem with release/retain?

What happens if you just use @synthesize length; instead of a customer setter?